# A editable JTree converts the tree nodes into Strings

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I'm using a JTree that is populated from a database.

The tree is created by setting the root node and its childs with custom objects this way:

```
private DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode("Categorias");
...
ResultSet primaryCategories = dbm.fetchAllCategories();
while (primaryCategories.next()){
    Category category = new Category(primaryCategories.getLong("_id"), 
            primaryCategories.getString("category"));
    DefaultMutableTreeNode childNode = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(category);
    rootNode.add(childNode);

    ResultSet currentSubcategory = dbm.fetchChildSubcategories(category.getCatId());
    while (currentSubcategory.next()){
        Category subcategory = new Category(currentSubcategory.getLong("_id"), 
                currentSubcategory.getString("category"));
        childNode.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(subcategory, false));
    }
}
...
```

After this, the tree is perfectly created. Populated with "**Category**" Objects, every object has its own ID number and its name to use in toString() method.

The problem comes when it's set editable. Once the node is renamed, the **Category** node is also converted into a **String** Object, so I cant update the new Category name value to the database.

I've tried to capture the renaming event with `treeNodesChanged(TreeModelEvent e)` but, the userObject is already changed to a String Object, and can't get a referece of what object was edited.

What way can I solve this? Should I have a copy of the tree that's shown and another of the downloaded from the database and uptade both everytime a change occurs?

**PD: **
I also tried to capture the changed node from the model overriding the method:

```
public void nodeChanged(TreeNode newNode) {
   DefaultMutableTreeNode parent = ((DefaultMutableTreeNode)newNode.getParent());
    int index = getIndexOfChild(parent, newNode);
    DefaultMutableTreeNode oldNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) getChild(parent, index);
    System.out.println(parent.getUserObject().getClass().toString());
    System.out.println(oldNode.getUserObject().getClass().toString());          
}
```

this prints:

```
class com.giorgi.commandserver.entity.Category
class java.lang.String
```

So the old node here has already been changed to a String and I've lost completely the reference to the older Category and its ID so I cannot update it in the database.

Any help is wellcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, that took a bit of digging.

Basically, when the editing is "stopped", the `JTree` will request the editor's value via editor's `getCellEditorValue`.  This is then passed to the model via the `valuesForPathChanged` method, which finally calls the node's `setUserObject` method.

Presumably, you are using either the default editor or one based on text field.  This will return a `String` value.

What you need to do is trap the change to the `setUserObject` method of your tree node, access the value coming (ie, check if it's a `String` or not) and update as required.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I'll be looking into it right now

Comment: lol, never done editing in `JTree`, it was fine digging around to figure out how it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Final solution was as MadProgrammer said to get it in:

```
public void valueForPathChanged(TreePath path, Object newValue) {
        DefaultMutableTreeNode aNode = (DefaultMutableTreeNode)path.getLastPathComponent();
        Category catNode = (Category) aNode.getUserObject();
        catNode.setCategory((String) newValue);
        catNode.updateFromDatabase();
        nodeChanged(aNode);
    }
```